# <C-space> does nothing in YouCompleteMe

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

I'm on my 4th clean install of YouCompleteMe.  I am trying to get  to work with a Python file after a `.` (such as `foo.`...Then I hit `<C-space>` and would hope to see a list of options to complete with), but so far, nothing seems to be getting through.

This is the situation:

```
i  <C-Space>   * <C-X><C-O><C-P>
    Last set from ~/dotfiles/vim/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
```

From `.vimrc`:

```
let g:ycm_python_binary_path = '/usr/bin/python'
let g:ycm_server_python_interpreter = '/usr/bin/python2'
let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion = 2
```

And I've got no errors or warnings from the `YcmDiags` or any other YCM logs.

If I go ahead and type 2 characters (assuming they match a possible completion), the completions appear very quickly, so I believe the call is being made and serviced properly in that context.  It's just calling it up manually with the key-binding is unresponsive.

I'm running xfce4-terminal and using `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`, but I hope nothing there would be the culprit, like for example the terminal is blocking `<C-space>` from getting to Vim.

Oh, and I'm running Vim 8.0 on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You actaully need to map to `<Nul>`, not to `<C-Space>` - looks strange I know, but I learned that recently trying to map to `<C-Space>`. I looked how it's done in CtrlSpace plugin, and it's using `<Nul>` for that. The reason is that your terminal probably send's `^@` (Nul character/sign) on <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> - you can check that in `Insert Mode` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd>. The downside is that `<Nul>` can be triggered from other key sequences, not only <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd>.

Edit:
[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344382/1199156) a related SO answer with a bit different approach. It maps `<Nul>` directly to `<C-Space>`